# Android Glide and Firebase Storage: Load Consecutive Images from Firebase Storage to Imageview - Flickering

Tags: android, firebase, android-glide

I am trying to achieve to consecutivly download pictures from firebase storage into an imageView in an android app. 
So far I succeeded but the result is more or less terrible because updating the image causes a flickering, i.e. a blank image between both images.

I store the most recent picture path in a firebase realtime database in the node "state/recentPicture". Everytime this is updated i fetch it in my android app via an ValueEventListener and then update my image view via glide. The framerate of the pictures is 3 per second. 
My code lookes like this:

```
mFirebaseDatabase.child("state").child("recentPicture").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Log.d("Picture Update:",dataSnapshot.toString());
            String imgPath = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child(imgPath);
            Glide.with(getContext())
                    .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
                    .load(mStorageRef)
                    .fitCenter()
                    .crossFade()
                    .into(mImageView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

The image loader class is directly copied from the github page of firebaseUI:
[FirebaseImageLoader from FirebaseUI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/storage/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/storage/images/FirebaseImageLoader.java)

I am thinking that maybe I need to buffer multiple images before starting the process of putting them into my imageview.

Has anyone better suggestions. In the long run I want to "simulate video streaming" via still images. The images are more or less live images. Maybe the whole approach using firebase database and firebase storage is wrong. If you got any better suggestions, I would be glad to hear them.

As an additional information I would like to add, that the imageview resides in a fragment. I also already tried omitting the crossfade function and also used dontAnimate() and dontTransform(), but neither showed any improvement.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:
I am using on resource ready and a SimpleTarget. The downloadpaths are buffered in an ArrayList.

The value listener looks like this.

```
  mFirebaseDatabase.child("state").child("recentPicture").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Log.d("Picture Update:",dataSnapshot.toString());
            String imgPath = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            if (imgPath!= null) mPictures.add(imgPath);
            if (mPictures.size()==1){
                mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child(imgPath);
                Glide.with(getContext())
                        .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
                        .load(mStorageRef)
                        .asBitmap()
                        .fitCenter()
                        .into(target);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

The simple target like this:

```
    private SimpleTarget target = new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {

    @Override
    public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(resource);

        if(mPictures.size()>=1){
            String imgPath = mPictures.get(0);
            Log.d("Printing picture:",imgPath);
            mPictures.remove(0);
            mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child(imgPath);
            Glide.with(getContext())
                    .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
                    .load(mStorageRef)
                    .asBitmap()
                    .fitCenter()
                    .into(target);
        }

    }
};
```

And the image paths are stored in a private field:

```
    private ArrayList<String> mPictures = new ArrayList<>();
```